# San Francisco as web safe font

Tags: web, fonts

I'm developing a microsite for an iOS app and I'm thinking to use the new Apple's San Francisco font on it. Obviously I can't use it as a webfont because of the licensing, but I think using it as safe font shouldn't be a problem...

I've tried using "sf ui text" as font-family and it works perfectly in Mac OS (El Capitan) but I can't get it on iOS 9.

Does anybody know why it doesn't work on iOS? I've tried all the official San Francisco names I've found but it's still showing the default sans-serif (Helvetica).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you... didn't actually ask a question yet. Do you just want to know what the system name for San Fransisco is? (if so, surely that information can be found with google?)

Comment: Updated with a concrete question.

Comment: I used google with "san francisco as web font on ios 9" for you, and found https://www.webkit.org/blog/3709/using-the-system-font-in-web-content

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't found this. Works perfectly.